# How to convert decimal to scientific in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named `Product`. The table looks like this:

```
ID   Product           Volume
1      xyz       4654.000000000000000
2      abc       121.000000000000000
```

I want to represent `Volume` in a scientific notation. `Volume` is of datatype `decimal(20,8)`.

How can I do this conversion?

Comment: I'd suggest doing this in the presentation layer. Assuming you have one that is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the formatting and presentation of data should be done by UI, on the client side, but if you insist...

```
DECLARE @t decimal(20,8) = 4654.000000000000000;
SELECT @t, CONVERT(nvarchar(32), CAST(@t as float), 2)
```

**result**

```
4654.00000000   4.654000000000000e+003
```

First `CAST` `decimal` to `float` (please note, it may loose precision), then [`CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) `float` to `nvarchar` using style `2`:

> Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.

**Note**

[`float`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms173773.aspx) type has only 15 digits of precision, so it can't store your `decimal(20,8)` without loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t decimal(20,8)=132423423421.00000000
print  cast(@t as float)
```

you can cast volume field to float in select statement and then you will get scientific notation of it as shown above.

Comment: I tried it. it simply removes the 0's after decimal point and shows me the result. If I understood you correctly, you meant to say that I should use : Select cast(float,volume) as Volume from Product ?

Comment: Yes you understood correctly, but can you please let  me know according to your requirement what should  be the out out of 4654.000000000000000 and 121.000000000000000?

Comment: I only want those to be shown in Scientific notataion. As an example it should be like this : 8.71597853672E+001